# How to modify the openlayer3 input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, openlayers, openlayers-3

Currently I am developing the program using the openLayer3 API.
The input values in the source code below use the data that is clicked from the user.
The user clicked Lat-Lon like: start = [31.032741,119.211365]  end = [32.032741, 129.211365].

However, I do not want to receive the input value from the user, but I want to receive the data of the array format from the server and display it immediately.
For example https://openlayers.org/en/v4.0.1/examples/data/openflights/flights.json

map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Draw({  <-- It seems that this part is receiving user input data.
map.addLayer(  <--  This seems to be a solution, but it is only my guess.

If possible, please let me know in detail, but if not, please give me a rough guide.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>LineString Arrows</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.0.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
  <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.0.1/build/ol.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map" class="map"></div>

<script>
  var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  });

  var source = new ol.source.Vector();

  var styleFunction = function(feature) {
    var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
    var styles = [
      // linestring
      new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#ffcc33',
          width: 2
        })
      })
    ];

    geometry.forEachSegment(function(start, end) {
      var dx = end[0] - start[0];
      var dy = end[1] - start[1];
      var rotation = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
      // arrows
      styles.push(new ol.style.Style({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(end),
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
          src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.0.1/examples/data/arrow.png',
          anchor: [0.75, 0.5],
          rotateWithView: true,
          rotation: -rotation
        })
      }));
    });

    return styles;
  };
  var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source,
    style: styleFunction
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [raster, vector],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [-11000000, 4600000],
      zoom: 4
    })
  });

  map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ ('LineString')
  }));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question quiet clearly. Do you want to do something like [this](https://openlayers.org/en/v4.0.1/examples/polygon-styles.html), based on your own coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to load the **json** data or **geojson** data.

I have the solution for **geojson** format.

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.0/examples/data/geojson/line-samples.geojson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});
var styleFunction = function(feature) {
    var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
    var styles = [
        new ol.style.Style({
            stroke : new ol.style.Stroke({
                color : '#ffcc33',
                width : 2
            })
        }) 
    ];
    geometry.forEachSegment(function(start, end) {
        var dx = end[0] - start[0];
        var dy = end[1] - start[1];
        var rotation = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        styles.push(new ol.style.Style({
            geometry : new ol.geom.Point(end),
            image : new ol.style.Icon({
                src : 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.0.1/examples/data/arrow.png',
                anchor : [ 0.75, 0.5 ],
                rotateWithView : true,
                rotation : -rotation
            })
        }));
    });
    return styles;
};
var vectorLines = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source : source,
    style: styleFunction
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
             new ol.layer.Tile({
                 source: new ol.source.OSM()
             }),
          vectorLines
        ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [-8161939, 6095025],
        zoom: 8
    })
});
map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source : source,
    type : 'LineString'
}));
```

Use this code inside the script tag it will work as you expected. But I don't know how to load the json array. If you find out share with us.

Comment: I am currently working on four projects at the same time, so I can confirm the answer at this time. This answer is what I was looking for. Thank you so much~!! ^^

Comment: If you know how to load the **json array** share with us.